# In Affinity Designer, How do I export a document with multiple artboards to a single page PDF file

Tags: pdf, export, artboard, affinity-designer

In Affinity Designer 1.7 (Desktop), when exporting a document with multiple artboards to PDF, each artboard is placed in a different page inside the PDF file. How do I avoid this behaviour and export a single page PDF file containing all of my artboards exactly as in my document?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In *Export Persona* in the *Slices* Panel export the **background**.

Note there are slice settings for each Slice/Artboard:

[image: Slices Panel]